# Touchpad right click is not working - Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell inspiron 5548

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell inspiron 5548.
I have problem with touchpad.Touchpad left click and touch works fine. But right click never works. Right click triggers left click.
Meanwhile, everything works just fine with external mouse. And touchpad works perfectly in Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings - Mouse & Touchpad

And change primary click to left /or right depending on what you want.

Comment: Primary click is left, and I want it to be left. The issue I'm facing is not related to this

Comment: Oh, from what you write it seemed like the mouse buttons wheere flipped

Comment: But if you changethis setting does both buttons become right?

Comment: Nope, they have not flipped. Both are doing primary click, i.e, what happens when you double tap on touchpad. And as I mentioned on question, external mouse, i.e, wireless mouse is working perfectly. So we can close the solution of settings -> Mouse/Touchpad one.